# how to explode a structs array

Tags: struct, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a schema like this

```
root
 |-- CaseNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Interactions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EmailInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- PhoneInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Contact: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CreatedOn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Direction: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- WebInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

and I would like to explode the three arrays(EmailInteractions,PhoneInteractions,WebInteractions) and group with CaseNumber and create three tables and  execute this sql query

```
Select casenumber,CreatedOn
from EmailInteration
where Direction = 'Outgoing'

union all

Select casenumber,CreatedOn
from PhoneInteraction
where Direction = 'Outgoing'

union all

Select casenumber,CreatedOn
from WebInteraction
where Direction = 'Outgoing'
```

the code to retrieve the schema

```
val dl = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("adl://power.azuredatalakestore.net/Se/eventhubspace/eventhub/0_2020_01_20_*_*_*.avro")
val dl1=dl.select($"body".cast("string")).map(_.toString())
val dl2=spark.read.json(dl1)
val dl3=dl2.select($"Content.*",$"RawProperties.UserProperties.*")
```

I am new to databricks, any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: But that's not a JSON Schema; it's not translatable to a JSON Schema.  Maybe edit your question to show the actual schema.

Comment: Since it is reading from Json, I thought it is a json schema, my bad. the above one is the actual schema. that is the one I wanted to flatten.